# Unable to run Xdebug from browser with Apache but works in PHP CLI

Tags: php, apache, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am working in an old PHP 5.4.16 environment on CentOS 7.9. I am trying to run Xdebug 2.4.1 with the PHP Debug extension in VSCode. I was able to get debugs to run remotely to my VSCode with the following launch.json config:

```json
{
    "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "hostname": "dev-internal.contoso.com",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "port": 9000,
    "log": true,
    "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/",
    }
}
```

I am running under an SSL VPN to connect to the web server with PHP. For some reason I can get debug information when I run scripts directly on the server with CLI, like `php index.php`. However if I initiate the request with a browser and use an extension, which sets the `XDEBUG_SESSION` to `XDEBUG_SESSION=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE`, I never get a response in the debugger.

This is what my PHP.ini looks like:

```ini
zend_extension="/opt/remi/php54/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000

xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1

;Disable connect_back if using remote_host
;xdebug.remote_host = 10.212.129.201
xdebug.log = /var/log/httpd/xdebug.log

xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/httpd/xdebug_remote.log
```

I can't seem to get it to with or without `remote_host` set. I also confirmed `_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` is set to the remote network's (of the web server) gateway IP address. The VPN client I am making requests from should come from 10.212.129.201 but Apache sees it as 192.168.21.1. I can ping 10.212.129.201 from the Apache server.

Ideally I am trying to get `remote_connect_back` to work so I can have two developers work on this over the VPN simultaneously. Also noticed that even when I can debug with the CLI, I can't step into functions.

Update:
Per LazyOne, I ran your php script in the CLI and got the script to run in my local Vscode. The output for xdebug_remote.log

```
Log opened at 2022-04-05 14:14:11
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000. :-|
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/test.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.4.45" protocol_version="1.0" appid="21459" idekey="root"><engine version="2.4.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_get -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="1" feature_name="resolved_breakpoints" supported="0"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

<- feature_get -i 2 -n notify_ok
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="2" feature_name="notify_ok" supported="0"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

<- feature_get -i 3 -n extended_properties
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="3" feature_name="extended_properties" supported="0"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

<- step_into -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="4" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/html/test.php" lineno="1"></xdebug:message></response>

<- stack_get -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="5"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/html/test.php" lineno="1"></stack></response>

<- context_names -i 6 -d 0
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="6"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

<- context_get -i 7 -d 0 -c 0
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="7" context="0"><property name="$a" fullname="$a" type="uninitialized"></property><property name="$b" fullname="$b" type="uninitialized"></property><property name="$c" fullname="$c" type="uninitialized"></property></response>

<- context_names -i 8 -d 0
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="8"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

<- property_get -i 9 -d 0 -c 0 -n "$a"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="property_get" transaction_id="9" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="300"><message><![CDATA[can not get property]]></message></error></response>
```

This is the output from the debug console in VSCode:

```
-> evaluateRequest
{
  command: 'evaluate',
  arguments: { expression: '$a', frameId: 1, context: 'hover' },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 12
}

xd(1) <- context_names -i 8 -d 0
xd(1) -> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="8"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>
xd(1) <- property_get -i 9 -d 0 -c 0 -n "$a"
xd(1) -> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="property_get" transaction_id="9" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="300"><message><![CDATA[can not get property]]></message></error></response>
<- evaluateResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 12,
  command: 'evaluate',
  success: false,
  message: 'can not get property'
}
```

Also to be clear VSCode PHPDebug plugin has a connection to the server, this is how it connects on "localhost", see log OUTPUT in VSCode:

```
[07:14:00.098] Remote server is listening on 40562
[07:14:00.098] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":40562},"osReleaseId":"centos","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/run/user/0","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"11aa11aa-1aa1-1aa1-a111-111a11aaa1a1"},"serverStartTime":118,"installUnpackCode":""}
[07:14:00.099] Starting forwarding server. localPort 65166 -> socksPort 65156 -> remotePort 40562
[07:14:00.100] Forwarding server listening on 65166
[07:14:00.100] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[07:14:00.101] [Forwarding server 65166] Got connection 0
[07:14:00.101] Tunneled 40562 to local port 65166
[07:14:00.101] Resolved "ssh-remote+spos-dev" to "127.0.0.1:65166"
[07:14:00.106] ------




[07:14:00.115] [Forwarding server 65166] Got connection 1
[07:14:00.123] > 
[07:14:00.363] [Forwarding server 65166] Got connection 2
```

If you run a netstat on the Apache/PHP/Xdebug server you'll see:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37936         127.0.0.1:40562         ESTABLISHED 21108/sshd: root@no
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37528         127.0.0.1:9000          TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37604         127.0.0.1:9000          ESTABLISHED 21602/php
tcp        0      0 192.168.21.249:22       192.168.21.1:65102      ESTABLISHED 20976/sshd: root@pt
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40562         127.0.0.1:37936         ESTABLISHED 21182/node
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40562         127.0.0.1:37938         ESTABLISHED 21262/node
tcp        0      0 192.168.21.249:22       192.168.21.1:65158      ESTABLISHED 21108/sshd: root@no
tcp        0      0 192.168.21.249:22       192.168.21.1:65101      ESTABLISHED 20974/sshd: root@pt
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37938         127.0.0.1:40562         ESTABLISHED 21108/sshd: root@no
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          127.0.0.1:37604         ESTABLISHED 21448/node
tcp6       0      0 192.168.21.249:443      192.168.21.1:59548      FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp6       0      0 192.168.21.249:443      192.168.21.1:59547      FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp6       0      0 192.168.21.249:443      192.168.21.1:59549      FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp6       0      0 192.168.21.249:443      192.168.21.1:59550      TIME_WAIT   -
```

Comment: PHP 5.4 is no longer supported. And neither is Xdebug 2. Xdebug 3 has many new features including much better logging to tell you what is going wrong. Please upgrade. In any case, I doubt `remote_connect_back` is going to work. Hard code the IP address of your IDE with `xdebug.remote_host`.

Comment: You have Xdebug log enabled. Great. Clear it and try to debug a CLI script (you said the debug works here). Save that log elsewhere (copy to local), empty it and now try to debug the web page. Check the log again -- do you see any differences? Do they use the same IP addresses? etc. **I suggest** you try to debug the same PHP code in both cases (a simple small script like this with each command on own line: `<?php $a = 1; $b = 2; $c = $a + $b; echo "$c\n";`). Share those logs here (you may redact the project name if needed but keep as much as possible of the orig info).

Comment: It would be interested to see where the difference is. If the IP is the same in both cases but it works only for CLI ... it could be your CentOS config, e.g. SELinux in action (that denies making outgoing connections for Apache controlled processes and you will have to configure it to allow that.)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions LazyOne, I updated the original post with log outputs for that sample script. I would be very interested to see what SELinux config you are referring to. I can see there's an setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect option, perhaps that is what you are referring to? I've never used these SELinux commands, I'm more familiar with Debian-based systems.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206339279-Xdebug-can-not-connect-to-PhpStorm-on-OS-X-Mavericks?page=1#community_comment_206899645 -- `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`

Comment: 1) `xdebug.remote_connect_back` is not used for CLI (for obvious reasons: such headers are available in webserver/HTTP context only).

Comment: 2) *"connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000"* -- this and your 3rd added snippet tells that you must be using SSH tunnel for Xdebug connection forwarding (could be done automatically by VSCode for you, not sure). Therefore, maybe it's not used when you do your web page debug? Sorry, I'm not using VSCode myself (and when I used it it was local Windows debug only) so cannot help on this part.

Comment: I'm using PhpStorm and can suggest to check this article (PHP debug over SSH tunnel). It may give you some hints (at very least it describes the overall process/setting up the tunnel; PhpStorm specific part you can ignore or "translate" to VSCode way of doing it). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html